# Flutter: Fetching posts within a radius in flutter (1-time query) - GeoFlutterFire

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, data-retrieval

I am developing an application that works with GeoFlutterFire.

**What Does it Do (Application)**

I want to retrieve posts within a certain area radius in my application.

**What's wrong**

I am able to fetch posts but all the posts are being retrieved with **Stream Builder**, which causes the data to change while the users are viewing it, or even if they are not viewing it and the post is just below the post they are viewing. This causes additional reads, which are expensive.

**What I want**

I want to do 1-time query for the posts, and on the user's request fetch more posts... ***developer-friendly pagination***.

I am doing it using ***geoflutterfire_plus: ^0.0.18***, which is the art-of-the-state replica of the original package ***GeoFlutterFire***

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)